# "Failed to load dynlib/dll" While executing the "*.exe " file after binding it with PyInstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, pyinstaller, sklearn-pandas

The code successfully works while executing using CMD , but when it is binded to `*.exe` file using Pyinstaller, It throws an error and stops executing (the Message is given below). I tried all possible solutions by linking the path library and other stuff too.

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and will be removed in 3.3.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 167, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed Hashim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "C:\Users\Mohammed Hashim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sklearn\_distributor_init.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "site-packages\pyinstaller-4.0.dev0-py3.7.egg\PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 169, in __init__
__main__.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Users\\MOHAMM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI38242\\sklearn\\.libs\\vcomp140.dll'. Most probably this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[13968] Failed to execute script try
```

Previously , It was `[11496] Failed to execute script try` with similar error message.

I also hereby share my code. (this code was written to check the missing library and Error Message - Handy error detection)

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import datasets

data = pd.read_csv(r"D:\PROGRAMS\DATASETS\Kang_nose_data_csv.csv")

print(data.head())
```

It produces similar error for sklearn,numpy and pandas and many other libraries.
Thanks...!

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4648#issuecomment-636431662